# Simple Requirements Management

Tags: markdown, requirements

Looking for a vary simple way to manage requirements using text editor, the following is desird:

- Can be easily edited by developers, readable in text
- Can be converted to PDF document for managers
- revisions can be tracked on git
- it can be broken up into chapters and sections
- Images can be added to requirement document.
- Paragraphs introducing the chapter can be added.

I tried LaTeX, its just not working, too many rules, too complex.

So each Requirement has 6 fields.

1. Requirement Number (1 to 4 digit integer)
2. Depends on (Line above)
3. Requirement Name
4. Class (4 to 10 chars)
5. Priority (required or optional)
6. Requirement string

So I have tried to do the following which works ok in markdown

```
Req  | Belongs |    Name         | Class | Priority
-----|---------|-----------------|-------|---------
1209 | 1208    | File Delimiters | sysrs | required

Each file is enclosed in curly braces ``{}''.
____
```

But i do not like to always having to adjust the spacing in "name field" when the name length changes.  So I tried the following:

```
---
** 1209 ** >>> 1208, File Delimiters, sysrs, required

Each file is enclosed in curly braces ``{}''.
___
```

But it is little hard to read.  So I would love to make it like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1209 | File Delimiters | 1208 | sysrs | required
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Each file is enclosed in curly braces ``{}''.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but markdown turns both of the lines into titles.  Would anyone have any recommendations?  Would like to avoid writing scripts to change the format.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with markdown: Pandoc's [grid tables](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#extension-grid_tables) can be created easily using Emacs table mode.